# Optional Parameter Routing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I am experiencing an issue with a routing parameter in my `[HttpPost] Edit ActionResult`

In that action I have a conditional statement checking what the user tries to enter into the database against what is already in the database.. and if they match then throw an error saying that that record already exists.

```
if (oLevel.PostPreID == 2)
{
    if (db.OL.Any(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(oLevel.Date) && x.PostPreID == oLevel.PostPreID && x.AID == oLevel.AID && x.deleted == false))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("PostPreID", "There is already a record for this Date!");
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = oLevel.AID, alreadyExists = true }); ;
    }                     
}
```

That obviously redirects back to my `[HttpGet] Edit ActionResult` to show the user the original record (or at least trying to get it to do that)

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, bool alreadyExists)
    {
        try
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            OL oLevel = db.OL.Find(id);
            if (oxygenLevel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            if (alreadyExists == true)
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('There is already a record for this Date!');</script>");
            }


            return View(oLevel);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            OL oLevel = db.OL.Find(id);
            if (oLevel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(oLevel);
        }

    }
```

but when testing this, it gives me this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'alreadyExists' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Boolean)' in 'AviationLogSummary.Controllers.OxygenLevelsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

I have tried this redirecting to the *Index* action and that worked, but not for the *Edit* action.  How do I get this to work?

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have just tried changing the `bool alreadyExists` to `bool? alreadyExists` and that does allow me to view the `[HttpGet] Edit ActionResult` but when I try and edit something that I know is a duplicate and will throw that alert I get **HTTP Error 404**

Comment: Not related but `ModelState.AddModelError` is pointless if your redirecting

Comment: @StephenMuecke good point. I will remove that

Comment: The code you have shown will not cause that error. Are you sure you do not have another `return RedirectToAction("Edit" ,... )` somewhere

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are talking about the **404 Error** or the original error?

Comment: The original (_null entry for parameter 'alreadyExists'_)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah in my update, I changed the `bool alreadyExists` to `bool? alreadyExists` and that fixed that error, but now when I change something in a record that I know will be a duplicate in the database and will throw the alert, it is now giving me a **404 error**

Comment: I would have expected it to read public ActionResult Edit(int? id, bool alreadyExists=false)

Comment: @BugFinder if I declare that parameter as false then it couldn't be changed to true when it needs to be.

Comment: Changing it to `bool?` wont really fix anything (if it was `null` before, it will just be `null` again (just without the error). You must have other code that is redirecting to the method but not passing the value of `alreadyExists`

Comment: @StephenMuecke this might be a stupid question but what if I created another `[HttpGet] Edit ActionResult` with a different method signature that doesn't include `bool? alreadyExists`?

Comment: And you can delete all the code inside your `catch` block (its just repeating the code in the `try` block so if that threw an exception, then the code on the catch block will throw it again). And please remove that awful `Response.Write()`. Pass a value of the view and then display your message in the view based on it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke care to put what you're saying in an answer?

Comment: No need to create another method. If you calling that method in other code where you do not want to pass a value for `alreadyExists` then you can make it `nullable`, But my point is that the code you have shown in the first snippet will not throw that exception - it must be caused by other code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay I get what you're saying. I am not calling the `[HttpGet] Edit ActionResult` in any other code.. I tried debugging and put a breakpoint next to the `[HttpGet] Edit ActionResult` where I was expecting the error but the error occurs before the breakpoint is hit..

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Weird - normal c# says if no value provided assume false, not ONLY be false.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, You will never enter the code in the `Edit()` method if you do not provide a value for `bool alreadyExists` (because the error is thrown while initializing the method). Despite what you think, you are calling the method somewhere else (and not providing the value) because the code you have shown will not throw that error. And to test, in the method where that first snippet of code is, add the following as the first line of code - `return RedirectToAction("Edit",new { id = 1, alreadyExists = true });` (change the `id` to a value you know exists) and you will see that it works.